# h2 test inside div properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

is there any way to fix h2 text inside div?

```css
.desc {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  font: Tahoma;
  color: #000;
  float: left;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #000;
}
.desc p {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #000;
}
.desc h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="desc">
  <p>
    <h2>Hello World</h2>
  </p>
</div>
```

as you see in this screenshot the height is actually 20px http://imgh.us/img22.png

it make problem while designing it won't stay on the size i want

Comment: You have a `height: 20px;` declared for `.desc`. Not sure what you what you mean by _it won't stay on the size i want_

Comment: i want the div on height 20px. but it stays on 51px

Comment: It doesn't look like chrome likes having an `<h2>` tag inside a `<p>` tag. Consider using something other than `<p>` if you need the header to be wrapped in it.

Comment: Also, I converted the code to use a snippet and when I inspect the element in Chrome I see that the div is the expected 20px. What browser are you using to test this out?

Comment: `<h2>` is a block tag, same as `<p>`. You don't need both, so pick one to remove and merge your CSS styles, e.g.: `.desc p { font-style: normal; font-weight: 100; color:#000; padding: 0; margin: 0; text-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #000; font-size: 11px; }`

Comment: i don't need <p> if you can fix the div for me with h2

Comment: i am using chrome. when i upload the page it is fine. but i am talking while designing

Comment: oh last code you give me it worked removing <p>

Comment: What program are you using to design the page? Sounds like that might not render the same way a browser would.

Comment: i think i will remove <p>

Comment: i am using dreamwaver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<h2>` is a block tag, same as `<p>`. You don't need both, so pick one to remove and merge your CSS styles, e.g.:

```
.desc p {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  color:#000;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #000;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK here is my new answer with some javascript to prove my point:

https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/1fahL6c0/6/

adding the inline style to your `<h2>` will change the height of the div back to 11px;

```
<body onload="getLineHeight();">
<div class="desc" id="height2">
            <p>
            <h2 id="height1">Hello World</h2>
            </p>
        </div>
<div class="desc" id="height4">
            <p> 
            <h2 id="height3" style="line-height: 11px;">Hello World</h2>
            </p>
        </div>

<script>
function getLineHeight(){
   var temp = document.getElementById('height1');
   var temp1 = document.getElementById('height2');
   var temp2 = document.getElementById('height3'); 
   var temp3 = document.getElementById('height4');  

   var ret = temp.clientHeight;
   var ret2 = temp1.clientHeight;
   var ret3 = temp2.clientHeight;
   var ret4 = temp2.clientHeight;
   alert("current line height"+ret+"  current div height"+ret2);
   alert("after my fix line height"+ret3+"  div height"+ret4); 

}
</script>
</body>
```